# can I really use an 8-bit address to map an ELF file?

Tags: c, x86-64, elf

So I'm trying to parse an executable and tell whether it's an ELF file or not, here's what I did:

```
    uint64_t *mapped_file = mmap(NULL, st.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);

    if (mapped_file[0] != 0x7f || strcmp(&mapped_file[1], "ELF"))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s is not an ELF file\n", argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Since I'm on a 64-bit machine I reckon that *uint64_t* is the appropriate type for the return value of mmap, however when I do this strcmp fails. I managed to solve this by using uint8_t instead but I'm not sure this is a valid approach. Are there any problems if I store a 64-bit address in a 8-bit variable?

Comment: First, you're not storing a 64bit address in an 8-bit variable. The code that "worked" (and, for mysterious reasons, was omitted from your post) is storing a 64bit address in a 64bit pointer, which *points to 8-bit values*. Related, are you're saying that first argument to `strcmp` did *not* throw a phat warning up when you compiled this? If it didn't, you need to add full warnings on your compiler toolchain. Lastly, I'm *fairly* sure that `&&` in your if-condition should be `||`. Could be wrong there, but that's an awfully odd condition if it's correct as-is.

Comment: @WhozCraig Actually both conditions have to satisfied for it to be an ELF file. As for the the warnings **-Wall** yields:  `warning: pointer targets in initialization of ‘uint8_t *’ {aka ‘unsigned char *’} from ‘char *’ differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
`

Comment: If as you say is the case, then if either of those condition as you have them in this code are true, (the lead byte is **not** 0x7F, or the subsequent three-character nullchar terminated string is **not** ELF, then it doesn't match as an ELF file preamble. That means the `&&` is *definitely* wrong. Keywords: *either* and *or*. Consider what happens with a simple file containing `0x10 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x00`. Well, the first condition is certainly true (0x10 != 0x7F), but the second condition is false. Do you see now why `||` is proper there?

Comment: @WhozCraig Oooh, you're right, my bad

Comment: This code might have a problem if someone attempts to load a file of 2 bytes in size.. and you're checking for "ELF" which is 3 bytes.. btw. You should validate the `st.st_size` result..

Comment: @Brandon: In theory yes, but I think Linux guarantees that bytes beyond the logical end of a file will be readable out to the end of a page on any architecture, potentially containing garbage.  And I think we can assume the page-size is greater than 5 bytes.  `strcmp` will never read farther than 4 bytes (`ELF\0`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pointer will always be the correct size for the machine. E.g. on a 64bit machine the pointer size will be 64-bit. What it points to is entirely up to you. Because you are looking at this as a byte array, the correct thing is to use pointer to 8-bit data, i.e. `uint8_t *mapped_file`. This is not an 8-bit pointer, but a pointer (64-bit in your case) to an array of 8-bit data.

Note with your string compare, `strcmp` will use a 0-terminated string. Unless the byte following "ELF" is a zero this will fail. Instead use `strncmp` where you can specify the length of the comparison to be restricted to 3 bytes.

The reason your code is failing is because you are specifying an array of 64bit values. So in the comparison `mapped_file[0] != 0x7f` you are actually comparing the 64bit (first 8 bytes of file) value to 0x7f. Similarly your offset at `&mapped_file[1]` will actually be starting at the 9th byte, not the 2nd.

Comment: Or better, `memcmp`.  You could even make a `const uint8_t magic[]={0x7F, 'E', 'L', 'F'};` and memcmp that to check all 4 bytes with one compare.  Making it an array of `uint8_t` avoids endian issues you'd get from doing a `uint32_t` compare in C.  (But a good compiler will still inline the memcmp as a single 32-bit compare instruction.)

Comment: Yup, just tried it.  `memcmp` compiles efficiently to a single cmp/jcc.  https://godbolt.org/z/GmMsPh, while `strncmp` compiles to a `rep cmpsb` with ECX=3 (slow microcode with startup overhead.)

Comment: @PeterCordes *memcmp* never crossed my mind, I'm going to use your version from now on :)